# Can Wix3.5 and Votive generate MSI installer for Windows Installer 4.0?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, setup-deployment, wix3.5, votive

Can I generate different Windows Installer versions (4, 4.5 or 5.0) .MSI from single Wix 3.5 VOTIVE of visual studio 2010.

Right now it is creating .msi which runs only on platforms with Windows Installer 5.0 (Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7).

I want it to generate .msi which can run on Platform with Windows Installer 4.0 (primarily Windows server 2008).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specify the lowest supported version of Windows Installer in the InstallerVersion attribute of the Package element:

For Windows Installer 4 or higher:

```
<Package InstallerVersion="400"
```

For Windows installer 4.5 or higher:

```
<Package InstallerVersion="405"
```

Comment: Super fast answer, I am not able to accept it as you answered in less than 5 minute. - Thanks.